# Infer decorator's argument's type from the type of the decorated function

Tags: typescript

I want to build a decorator that accepts an array of strings that need to be typesafe and to be the names of the keys of an argument that the function that is being decorated has.

For example, having the following setup:

```
type Params = {id: string};

class Test {
  @requiredParams('id', 'name')
  async handler(request: IRequest<void, Params>): Promise<void> {}
}
```

There should be e type error since `name` is not part of the `Params` interface.

Here is what I've got this far:

```
export function requiredParams<
    TRequestParams extends Record<string, string>,
    TRequiredRequestParams extends keyof TRequestParams & string
>(...requiredRequestParams: TRequiredRequestParams[]) {
    return function <
        TThis,
        TArguments extends Parameters<AsyncRequestHandler<any, TRequestParams, any>>,
        TReturn
    >(
        target: (this: TThis, ...args: TArguments) => Promise<TReturn>,
        context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<TThis, (this: TThis, ...args: TArguments) => Promise<TReturn>>,
    ) {
        return async function(this: TThis, ...args: TArguments): Promise<TReturn> { ... };
    };
}
```

Here are some of the types used here (some details omitted for brevity):

```
type AsyncRequestHandler<
    TBody = any,
    TParams = any,
    TQuery = any
> = (request: IRequest<TBody, TParams, TQuery>, response: IResponse, next?: Next) => Promise<void>;

interface IRequest<TBody = any, TParams = any, TQuery = any> {
    body: TBody;
    params: TParams;
    query: TQuery;
}
```

btw, this is using the new decorators implementation.

Attaching a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.0-dev.20230305#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewoF4oAoCUKB8UBuA9gJYAmA3AFCiRQCSAShAM5gEB2T0qA3gL4UUibYBABOAMwCGAY2gMIARwCuzYAB4AKgCECJECiiS2IADRQNABUmjJAWyYGjp8wEUVo-aie5uFKP6gAI10QAC5zHT1KAKgwazsmcMt4%202iA5TEw13cQSn4qcGgAQSYQNmlGDKZgAAkjEgAbMTU-AO0Qx2MTVv9km3tO0x7szMGKXFQ0UUUVavD5KvV2vTM%20hNW3TOwzaZZ2TnnGPY4IMzYEYAB%20cLhELGRcC1ECWyJONUJSbEoKcSVy4BEdhQabKIjTEhWfpMTRQhLYNAAOmRcWh4TQAGsICACOJzHD7BgANoAXSwvhi02ASlEbCgfwBQLpaGA1gA5hBgOEnGYsVlqqIhGyzCRmNJBWBgARRElCpDnpBRKAACJiiVS0RqEplCozVR1NiNZo8-EpJhmbzYDDc4xQCkxAJEPFoUVMcVESXSlDIVD-UXiIQQEjk4YOgKu92e0QGADygQAVhBpMBERzgDGAO5sJ4ERUqtUejUs9mc3nYjAAQjSYfyYf80n2SGlRDZQkkDQAspyABa6G2eKAR9XSxF4dsqKsCOuDgtR0fjriGUrlen-ZNM9DAbtvfs7PVzOiVWbAPfHA6H5isE5nC43C4h6cxJ3oCug4%20I1EJB%20PsNb54ZqBzgAgBRURnlENAAHIYAIWIUk5MQHDAZ48FIINEUgjBq0fWsf3pL00AbDgkE-WwoFxODoW-PDHWdV99xTUimCJUiyTtUMaICP8CAAoCoFA8C0AAAw7N4mCFEEZnBINKLsBCZSgAASbgAGVgEFNg2TQUiMF4REhKwjif34GjcJ-KkaTpZtWzYdsuy3XREUkMAwAaEAWW3c0oCJN9VFPK9OBvRAyWwmJeCXQxjB%20acLNpGc3WHURsN4PIBAZddgTfaTITNOAMxaGINCPVQCQcC4IENBxGAbUQSDUAUhTMBrNO2YYiqkiFiuqUqoHKyqoD5Cj2sWHqADIoGatlxiRZEss6hjSqSI9sq64BStJajJOpOL0sBYECrrDQNE87ppw0IpRDZJRbAq4AysQCqSAcAl5JhbVylWg0jU1E1huPUqLWMbBWrOxhtrYYYESMqBWUuzl0S3HdzGOt4zGRJzLsScwLqum7hCYe5HmeV53na8GQbrIiREQcIAGEGkkJgmHs3sSFVGrJA1Wn2GppYUa8jykaOk6oHR9ksfOy7rtugmcCgHMSYgTQwcs4HToCTbKU5Sylx1VdGWBQWJf5tHkXFpIcel-HrXl4m3iVsnVfYmiiOqbzfOqfz9lOQCLhJRxMeivDxAI12SJSci8TmoNVtKzW8OfNB6MWD8zRYlI2PtTiHW43iIBAsDpWE0SmYk6OSFkm6RAU5S1I0rSdL0gzQrwkzW6nPDYrpWG00RaR2waI290WL3r19u4W-8FLhmn-JpAZpnzFUZ2AgAAXL0qoNITCoAAel3mHu2gZCIFQgglAcIhbFciA8dZPa2DMGrpmTNyJqUNkOWqBwhNIIThkZnrbs9QmhTAYocBiHxiAkDMNwKApBwiTSgLwbYkkzwQAgeg8kyCO7%20HXh1IMpU8pQR3vvKAgA%20DcAOy7ADlzSCgMAw0TRiEey5BeRYUDSCwPgSQRB6kJIoNHueeQWC7Q4N4EAA).

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even using the new 5.0 decorators.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example in ts playground, I think I can solve this

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you want to add runtime check but don't want to change type of the function that is being decorated

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Sorry, could not do it

Comment: Why do you need the "new" implementation? What's wrong with the first in the playground?

Comment: Not much. Just wanted to adhere to the new implementation of decorators.